# Setting the UAC 'Publisher' Field for a Installanywhere2010 Installer

Tags: java, windows, installanywhere

When I open my installer(that I created using InstallAnywhere 2010), the UAC dialog appears with information about my installer. The field Publisher is 'unknown'.

How can i change the field Publisher from unknown to a required name ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to digitally sign your finished installer.

In the InstallAnywhere docs we find the following:

> You can digitally sign installers on Windows if you have a valid digital certificate. Digital signatures give end users the added security that comes with knowing that an installer came from a trusted source. It also prevents your customer from seeing a “Unknown Publisher” warning when they launch installers on Windows XP Service Pack 2 and later systems. To digitally sign installers, you essentially need thre [sic] files: a .pvk file (a private key), an .spc file  (the code signing certificate), and signcode.exe (the code signing tool from Microsoft). You can download  `signcode.exe` from Microsoft’s download center. It is included in a package called `codesigningx86.exe`. Signcode 
>   has a GUI mode, but can also run from the command line. The command line can be as simple as:
>
> `signcode /spc myCert.spc /v mypkey.pvk "install.exe"`
>
> Signcode has numerous command-line parameters. For more information about Signcode, search for `signcode.exe` in the MSDN Library.

Refer to this link at MSDN about the SignTool utility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx